# Can I get a bound of the following 2-norm of a sum of products of matrices and vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices, matrix-norms

I am seeking for help about whether the following inequality is true:

I have k rank-one real matrices in $R^{d\times d}$, $x_1x_1^T, x_2x_2^T,...,x_kx_k^T$, where each $x_i$ is a vector in $R^d$ and $||x_i||_2\leq 1$, and I have k real vectors $y_1,y_2,...,y_k$ in $R^d$ and $||y_i||_2\leq c$ for each i. $\lambda>0$. Is the following inequality true?

$||(\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^T+\lambda I)^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^Ty_i||_2\leq c\sqrt{d}$.

I have asked another question and get $||\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^Ty_i||_2\leq c\sqrt{d}||\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^T||_2$, previously I thought if I can get this, I will get the result by:

$||(\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^T+\lambda I)^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^Ty_i||_2\leq ||(\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^T+\lambda I)^{-1}||_2 ||\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^Ty_i||_2\\\leq c\sqrt{d}||(\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^T+\lambda I)^{-1}||_2 ||\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^T||_2\leq c\sqrt{d}$.

But this is not ture since I can not get $||(\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^T+\lambda I)^{-1}||_2 ||\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^T||_2  \leq 1$. Then, can we prove the inequality holds? I have tried to do some programming to check whether this bound is possible, and I found that in all the random generated examples, this bound holds, but I don't know whether we can prove it. If it does not hold or we can not prove this bound, is it possible to prove a looser bound like $cd$ in the RHS? I just want to get an upper bound that only depends on c and d, independent of k. Could you please help me?

Million thanks!

Comment: @Exodd Could you please help me with this? Thanks a lot！

Comment: it's false with if $d>1$ and $k>1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterexample is
$$x_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\left(\begin{array} 1
2\\1
\end{array}\right)= -y_1,\qquad
x_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\left(\begin{array} 1
0\\1
\end{array}\right),\qquad
y_2 = \sqrt 5 x_2,\qquad c=1
$$
and $\lambda$ small enough.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Is it possible to get an upper bound of this term independent of k? e.g., cd …

Comment: No, I think every such bound depends on $k,d,c$

Comment: OK, thanks very much for your help.